# How to remove from sub document based on conditions of another?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a Computer Card Game and am building the server component which will allow the player to create and design a deck. I am using GameSparks which uses Mongo as data store.

When the player pushes 'Save Deck' and sends the json document describing the deck she just built to the server, I want to validate on the server that the player actually owns all the cards she says she owns. I need a way to take this JSON document and remove any cards from it which are not actually owned by the player.

To complicate things - players can 'destroy' cards to gain 'dust', and I'll need to run the same check at that time to remove any instances of that card still found in any of her decks.

Is there a way to do this using the querying engine of Mongo? I am coming from a SQL Server background where stuff like this seems much easier. If not, should I loop through the JSON and remove the cards one at a time?

Here's the PlayerDeck document: (it contains a list of "DeckEntries" which have an "id" which represents the ID of the card)

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59f909269283f4cbf81a6e53"
  },
  "DeckID": "f36edf2d-7f76-4c58-8fcb-c5b273f65429",
  "DeckName": "New",
  "DeckEntries": [
    {
      "Id": "597f73ae46e0fb0001b8661d",
      "SlotPosition": 0
    },
    {
      "Id": "597f73ae46e0fb0001b865f3",
      "SlotPosition": 1
    }
  ],
  "HasOverriden": false,
  "PlayerID": "59ee3def5c3fba050ede62dc"
}
```

And here is the PlayerCards document: (it contains a "cards" sub document which contains a list of Ids representing the card ID, as well as the "count" which represents how many of that card the player has)

```
    {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59ee3def5c3fba050ede62e9"
  },
  "playerId": "59ee3def5c3fba050ede62dc",
  "dust": 12,
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": "597f73ae46e0fb0001b8660f",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "597f73ae46e0fb0001b86602",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "597f73ae46e0fb0001b8661d",
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example, the player is trying to save a deck containing 2 cards, card id "597f73ae46e0fb0001b8661d" and card id "597f73ae46e0fb0001b865f3".

In this example, the player owns 2 cards, "597f73ae46e0fb0001b8661d" and "597f73ae46e0fb0001b8660f".

So in this case, there is 1 card which the player is trying to save to his deck which he does not actually own ("597f73ae46e0fb0001b865f3").

How can I remove the item from DeckEntries with the ID of "597f73ae46e0fb0001b865f3" BECAUSE it does not exist in the PlayerDeck document? (I also need to remove if it does exist in PlayerDeck but the associated "count" is 0)

How can I remove from 'PlayerDeck' any cards which are no longer in  (or have a quantity of 0) the PlayerCards?

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking, and mostly since there seems to be no corelation between the two documents you include in the question other than the "player". You are also dangerously mixing `_id` and `Id` and even `id` rather than keeping a consistent naming. Also your "dump" here seems to indication that `PlayerID` actually contains a "string" as opposed to the [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) value it's meant to relate to which is **not a string**. And really, that's just a "few" of the problems.

Comment: The short shrift is you seem to be talking about "referential integrity". MongoDB has no such thing. Instead, you "design differently" or use a relational database. But mostly your question is far too unclear. We don't need to know the "rules of the game". Just specify actions. Has this data to update, here is the stored data, this is what needs to happen.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the comment, my apologies for the lack of clarity. I have edited the post to hopefully make clear my question. you're right about the ID's - it's a mess - I need to fix that, thank you for pointing that out. How could you tell that PlayerID was a string and not an ObjectId?